# how to access datagrid from another form

Tags: c#, user-interface

i am trying to access datagridview1 from another file which is Program.cs
the datagridview1 is in form1 but it always gives me an error
Form1 doesnt contain a definition for datagridview1

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.dataGridView1'

```
foreach (string i in AllCourses.Keys)
{
    if (TmpStd.coursesF.Contains(i) || TmpStd.coursesIP.Contains(i))
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (AllCourses[i].prerequired_courses == "None")
    {
        Form1.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, AllCourses[i].name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Form1 is not an instance, that's the problem. Google difference between class definition and its instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are having a design issue since you are trying to access a DataGridView from your Program.cs class.

Anyway, if you still want to do that, you have to change the Visibility property of tha DataGridView to 'Public' and then you will be able to access the way you want it.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>

    // I didn´t declare all you need

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Form1 yourForm = new Form1();
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(yourForm);

         foreach (string i in AllCourses.Keys)
        {
            if (TmpStd.coursesF.Contains(i) || TmpStd.coursesIP.Contains(i))
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (AllCourses[i].prerequired_courses == "None")
            {

                yourForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, AllCourses[i].name);
            }
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not make it public because then anyone can set your datagridview to something else from outside.

Comment: I know, thats why I told that it is probably design 'bad practice'

Comment: Don't make your datagridview public, you only need to make it static, and in your Form1.cs, write a public static method to access data from datagridview,. This way you can call this method in any class to just access data but has no right to change data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare Form1 first. Try this:

```
Form1 datagridForm = new Form1()

foreach (string i in AllCourses.Keys)
{
    if (TmpStd.coursesF.Contains(i) || TmpStd.coursesIP.Contains(i))
    {
        continue;
    }
    if (AllCourses[i].prerequired_courses == "None")
    {

    datagridForm.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i, AllCourses[i].name);
    }
}
```

Please note that depending on your overall implementation you may need to declare the Form1 variable differently or pass it in as part of the overall function.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely `dataGridView1` is private so you can not access it from outside the form.

If that is the case, in `Form1` create a property like this:

```
public DataGridView DataGridView1 { get { return this.data1ridview1; }}
```

Also, I would call the `datagridview` with a more meaningful name instead of `datagridview1`, for example, `dataGridViewStudents` or something more meaningful.

Then you can access it using an instance of the class where `DataGridView1` is in.

`Form1` is a class but this is not an instance of the class. So if a form is created like this:

```
Form1 myForm = new Form1();
```

Then 'myForm' is an instance of the class `Form1`. Then I can access the `datagridview` like this:

```
var grid = myForm.DataGridView1;
```